# How do you install VirtualBox and VMWare on Chromebook's Linux Virtual Machine (Debian/Bullseye)?

Tags: debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, chrome-book

I want to install VMWare or VirtualBox on my HP Chromebook x360's Linux Virtual Environment (Debian 11 Bullseye). The problem is that I do not know how to install it and I feel like I am missing a few things. I am not sure what is going on but it seems like I cannot install those programs for one reason or another. I really want to try hose programs if only out of curiosity. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualbox isn't officially maintained on Debian, that's why you can't install it from the regular repositories. VirtualBox can be installed on debian 11 from the [Fast Track repository](https://fasttrack.debian.net/).

Backports should be enabled:

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contib non-free" |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Adding Fast Track:

```
sudo apt install fasttrack-archive-keyring
```

The package `fasttrack-archive-keyring` is available in the main repository.

```
echo "deb http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ bullseye-fasttrack main contrib" |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ bullseye-backports-staging main contrib"
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox
sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack
```

You can install VirtualBox from Oracle repository. [See instructions
here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

[VMware's installation guide on Debian Wiki.](https://wiki.debian.org/VMware)

[VirtualBox installation instructions on Debian Wiki.](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_10_.22Buster.22.2C_Debian_11_.22Bullseye.22.2C_and_Debian_12_.22Bookworm.22)

Comment: Does it work on a Chromebook?

Comment: @GAP Does it work?